# insert not duplicate data with Pymongo in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Now,I try to insert data with pymongo in mongoldb.

```
get_db().users.update({'_id':ObjectId(session['user_id'])},{'$push':{'hme':ObjectId(id)}},upsert=True)
```

but,the method produce duplicate ObjectID.before try find_one().

```
if not ObjectId(id) in get_db().users.find_one({'_id':ObjectId(session['user_id'])})['hme']:
    get_db().users.update({'_id':ObjectId(session['user_id'])},{'$push':{'hme':ObjectId(id)}},upsert=True)
```

better method request..

may be use forEach.but syntax error

yang

Comment: how to close question?  stack overflow question done

Answer (score 0):

If the `hme` key holds arrays of `ObjectId`s then you could try the **[`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)** operator instead of the **[`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push)** since it adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case **[`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)** does nothing to that array thus it only ensures that there are no duplicate items added to the set and does not affect existing duplicate elements:

```
get_db().users.update(
   {'_id':ObjectId(session['user_id'])},
   {
       '$addToSet':{
           'hme':ObjectId(id)
       }
   },
   upsert=True
)
```